# How to make the entire area of a div clickable while excluding the checkbox that's on top of that area?

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I have a div with a checkbox inside the div:

```
<div class="study-box set-box">
    <span class="set-box-title"><i class="icon-th-list icon-white"></i>test set</span>
    <input class="study-box-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

I want the entire div to be clickable, so I can perform an onClick() event.  I don't want this event to be called when the checkbox is clicked, though.  I'm thinking about adding some areas to the left and bottom of the checkbox and binding the event to those areas, but this seems hackish.  Thoughts?

JSFiddle with a sample box/checkbox:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/59/

Comment: do you mean you want the checkbox click to happen when clicked anywhere on the div ?

Comment: No, I mean I want to do something when I click the div, but I don't want to do that something when I click the checkbox, which is inside the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop event propagation when the input is clicked.

```
$(".study-box").on("click", function () {
    console.log("clicked");
});
$("input").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/60/

Comment: @NOX I agree, it should actually be as specific as is necessary for the application.  I was just doing this purely as an example

Comment: but what happens when you want to fire off events on that checkbox? hence why I'd rather just check the target.

Comment: I'm using knockout binding on both the div and the checkbox, so I'm not sure if this would work.  I do need to call some methods when the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: This is the only way, since the checkbox is wrapped in the DIV. You would have to stop the animation from occurring if clicked on the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to create a wrapper and set that to position: relative (removing position: relative from the study box), and move the checkbox outside of the study box. It will still be positioned in the same way, but won't be affected by hovering and clicking on the study box.

Answer (score 0):

When a click event happens check the target.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('div.study-box').click(function (e) {
   console.log(e.target.tagName);     
    if(e.target.tagName == 'DIV'){
        // do something
    } else {
        // don't
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't suggest jQuery when it can be simply done by using HTML/CSS. The trick is,  place the checkbox outside of that div and push it visually inside the div using CSS position property. If you want to learn about CSS Position check out the following URL.

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-position.php